# Composer.json to autoload classes

Tags: php, json

I was following this tutorial on how to autoload classes, the guy teaching it already had Composer installed, he went ahead and created a composer.json file in his project directory with the following content:

```
{
    "autoload": {       
        "classmap": [       
            "./"        
        ]       
    }       
}
```

which supposedly autoloads any classes within the main project directory. And I cannot do this because if if I create a composer.json that is located anywhere but inside located in C:/Users/Mypc, the composer.json file cannot be found, I cannot install it in command line which is the tutorial's step, composer install creates his autoloading. My autoloader cannot seem to find any classes inside any path I create in the class map, be it absolute or relative, I also managed to install and move composer file to usr/local/bin/composer but that's all I can do.

I can't create an autoloader no matter what I do and I also can't move the composer.json to my project directory inside xampp/htdocs/myproject, because if I do so I can't composer install since composer.json can't be found. I am using xampp.

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: I am using windows 8.1.

Comment: You need to have the `composer.json` inside your project directory. What do you mean by " I also can't move the composer.json to my project directory"?

Comment: What i mean by that is, if i create a composer.json file, follow the tutorial's next step, wich consists of opening cmd and typing composer install i get another error wich says "composer could not find a composer.json file in C:\Users/My-PC please create a composer.json file described in composer.org, like i said in the question, "unless it is located in C:\Users\My-PC I apoligize for writting too fast i edited it and made it more understandable.

Comment: I had a similliar but minor problem before with creating a partials folder that just has the job of loading any .css file, wich was, the css couldn't be found because it was not installed in my computer since it was inside xampp, i had to create an absolute path.

Comment: `composer install` is used to install all dependencies in the composer.json (or lock) file. If you do not have a composer file yet you should generate one using `composer init`

Comment: I understand the first part, regarding the second one, i executed the composer init, i skipped most of the options such as name and license, now it asks me what are my dependencies (require) interactively yes? Also from what i saw in the tutorial, the person explaining already had the composer.json inside the main project wich is what i want to do.

Comment: I will sum it up here: Problem 1. If i create a composer.json like in the tutorial, composer.json can't be found unless its in C:\Users\My-pc. 2. If i create a composer.json in Users my-pc it can be found, but when i do composer install it cannot find any classes inside the all the paths i tried, be it absolute or relative path.

Comment: Regarding the composer init im stuck in search for a package and don't know what to type in.

Comment: have installed composer using exe file, if not it will be better if you will install it using exe file as you do not need to know too much, then can you confirm what you are getting in right click menu while you are on the same directory as composer.json .and also let me know the tutorial link that will be helpful to know your situation better.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/21 this is the link, and i am sorry but i don't understand what you mean, i did install it using exe file wich supposedly installs it globally, but what do you mean by right click menu n the same directory as composer.json?

Comment: If anyone comes up with a solution, please tell me step by step how do i install composer in cmd so it creates the autoload_classmap.php and all of the dependencies taking my problem of composer can't be found into account.

Comment: ok, can you share your routes.php in gist, you also need some .htaccess to make it work, I have gone through this tutorial :D

Comment: I have worked with htaccess before, i had to set up my server to route everything to a file.php, but my knowledge of it is very minor, here are my routes https://gist.github.com/DannyS95/3593f98e129cbdafde0cdb13ea8a681d

Comment: heck your gist.

Comment: im on it waiting for your or anyones answer.

Comment: I have recently downloaded a package, and the package is saved in C:\Users what i need is to save it on my project folder.

Comment: A friend of mine solved my problem through teamviwer, he had to change a bunch of things through command line and managed to download a package to my project directory, i dont know how he did it he told me not to worry about it, thanks to everyone who tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finaly found out what the issue was.
I simply had to use the change director with cd C:\whateverpath\totheprojectdir and then install the composer on whatever the project was on.